# JQuery autocomplete return into multiple fileds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have standard jQuery autocomplete function and pulling a data from SQL. It works but i would like to type information into field one and on select (after user is happy with result) complete filed one (code) and field 2 (description)

Fields:

```
<input type="text" name="code"  id="code" />
<input type="text" name="description"  id="description" />
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $("#code").autocomplete({
        source: "source.php",
        minLength: 0
    });                
});
});
```

PHP:

```
while ($row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$values[] = array('code'=>$row['code']                  
                ,'description'=>$row['description']     
                );
}
echo json_encode($values);
```

I check lots of questions already but nothing similar.

Comment: I found a good simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/f2aZ8/ and it working

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 $( function() {  
    var data = [];    
    $( "#code" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "source.php",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) { 
            var codes = []; 
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){                   
                 codes.push(data[i].code);
            }
            response(codes);
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
         for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].code == ui.item.label) {
               $('#description').val(data[i].description);
               break;
            }
          }
      }
    } );
  } );
```

Comment: I have error Uncaught TypeError: codes.map is not a function

Comment: Something wrong with the code new i have error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined_normalize